# Accessibility in UIWebView reads HTML code, not HTML page

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiaccessibility

this is strange error - I have UIWebView inside UITableView, and accessibility reads not content of html page, but instead reads RAW html data, including HTTP headers. Accessibility in UIWebView should work out of the box, right? What could cause such odd behaviour?

It's iphone 4S, ios 6.0 and xcode 4.5.2.

thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean, the UIWebView is inside a UITableView? Like it's added as a pull-down header, or it's in a cell? BTW, the iOS accessibility API is not exactly bug-free, so what you're describing doesn't surprise me.